# Printing out vowels from a sentence with no duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates

Using `def uniqueVowels(str):`, print out vowels with no duplicates. The vowels can be printed in any order but cannot be repeated. Assume `str` is a valid non-empty lower case string:

```
def uniqueVowels(str):
 vowels = "aeiou"
 for letter in str:
    if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
       vowels = list(set(vowels))
 print "Unique vowels:", vowels
```

I expect the output `uniqueVowels("dalhousie university")`

```
Unique vowels: aouie
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is this your homework? What have your tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have mistaken the name of the variable result so every time you print result it would be the same and also with all the vowels 
So you can modify you solution a little and that would work (the idea of your code is correct):

```
def uniqueVowels(str): 
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    result = list()
    for letter in str: 
        l = letter.lower()
        if ( l in vowels ) and (l not in result ):
            result.append(l)
    print ("Unique vowels:", result)

uniqueVowels("dalhousie university")
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the letter;

```
def uniqueVowels(string): 
    vowels = "aeiou"
    result = set()
    for l in string: 
        if l in vowels:
         result.add(l)
    print ("Unique vowels:", result)

uniqueVowels("dalhousie university")
```